# Nuxt3 + I18n - rootRedirect not working / blank page and no redirect

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt-i18n

I got a problem with Nuxt3 + i18n (@nuxt/i18n).

Everything works fine when navigating to the homepage like this:
http://localhost:3000/en or http://localhost:3000/nl

But when navigating to http://localhost:3000/ the application does absolutely nothing.

When inspecting via the browser, the `<div id="app"></div>` is empty.

I expect when I add `rootRedirect: "/en" that the app will redirect from / to /en. But it does'nt do that.

I've searched around all possible fixes on Stackoverflow and beyond, but nothing seems to work for me.

Anybody got some clues?

nuxt.config.ts
 `i18n: { locales: [ { code: "en", iso: "en", name: "English", file: "en.json", }, { code: "nl", iso: "nl", name: "Dutch", file: "nl.json", }, ], baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000", defaultLocale: "en", rootRedirect: "/en", lazy: true, strategy: "prefix", langDir: "locales", },`

Versions:

- "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.3",
- "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
- Node18